# Wordpress - Possible to rebuild with the database missing?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a small wordpress site that was hosted on a VPS and I decided to cancel the VPS a few days before the expiration and move to a cheaper provider as the blog was not getting a lot of visitors.

However because I did my backups in a hurry, I accidentally backed up the MySQL table instead of the actual wordpress table in MySQL. When I decided to restore the site yesterday, I noticed that and unfortunately my previous VPS has passed the expiration and my old provider confirmed that once the VPS is destroyed, they can no longer restore the data.

I do have the entire backup of the wordpress folder and my understanding is that the MySQL table is mostly just storing the settings and user info for Wordpress. So I was thinking if I could do a fresh install of Wordpress and populate the table in my new MySQL DB, and then replace everything by the backup copy of wordpress folder that I have, I should be able to get everything to work.

However when I tried that, I ended up having a blank page and nothing else. My PHP log weren't giving any error either.

Any suggestion?

Comment: no. the mysql table is EVERYTHING about the website. All your non-filebased content. Your site is **GONE**.

Comment: Might be a long-shot, but you can try this: http://archive.org/web/

Comment: Didn't work either unfortunately, it says the site was not cached...thanks anyways, looks like it is gone....

Comment: Well, if you had some readers and RSS, then you can try to ask them. Maybe they have some data stored still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your content is in the database too. So it's lost.

You can try scraping off content from Googles Cache and rebuild the site from scratch.

Sorry about that.

Comment: I tried to do http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://www.mysite.com but it looks like Google didn't cache the page either. I guess I lost it then. Oh well....